# View the actual mastery level in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

### In short

How can I view the actual mastery level of a League of Legends champion in a summoner profile page?

### Full details

I mean `actual` by the fact that the level displayed by the icon on champion avatar at loading screen is **not** the real level; the summoner is in the progress of collecting items for it.

Let's say the summoner i.e. me has reached level 7 for champion Jinx but not acquired enough item to make the level 7 icon yet.

So, where on my profile can I read my real champion level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that every level up after mastery level 5 is based on **performance** not on **experience**. You will gain infintely more experience if you continue to play after level 5 and the only upgrades will come by forging mastery 6 or 7 tokens. Those are gained by getting a rating of S- or higher for 6 and a rating of S or higher for 7. So if someone never manages to get a S- or higher with a champion but has 200k experience, lvl 5 is still his *real* level.

There is no way of seeing the amount of mastery tokens gained for a specific champion in the client itself if the account isn't your own. If you're looking for a method to find your own shards, you'll find them in the **Loot tab**. Your experience will be on the **Collections tab**. You'll see champion experience by hovering over the champion.

Please note that you will only see the experience of the top 3 champions of summoners you search via the chlient. The only way to find out how many champion points or "actual level" a summoner has is through 3rd party websites.

Personally I use [**masterypoints.com**](https://www.masterypoints.com). You can search for summoners and you'll see their mastery experience and tokens.

Comment: I think you mean *client* instead of *chlient*

Comment: Good site, There's also [ChampionMasteryLookup](http://championmasterylookup.derpthemeus.com/) which loads much faster and shows chests earned as well.